How to revert a smpl obj file back to its betas and thetas
I have an smpl-x body model obj file created and downloaded using meshcapade website. I need the betas and thetas used to create this obj file to deform garment to fit it. But meshcapade only provides the obj file not the parameters used to create it. Is there a way to revert this obj file to get the orignal betas and thetas used to create this mesh?
